# Cannot serialize list of objects as JSON in Django

Tags: python, json, django, web, serialization

I'm trying to pass some data about a user as JSON, and because the User object has many-to-many relationships, serializing a user as JSON seems to only include the primary key of the m-n object.
(e.g. each user has hobbies, but in the JSON it will only have the PK of the hobbies)

Anyway, I tried constructing a schema to solve this as such:

```
[[{user}, [hobbies]], [{user}, [hobbies]],...]
```

But whenever I try to serialize this (in Python it's basically an array with an object and another array in it), I get the error:

```
'list' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
Here's the code for it:

```
for u in allUsers:
    if searchedHobby in u.hobbies.all():
        user = [u]
        userHobbies = []

        for hobby in u.hobbies.all():
            userHobbies.append(hobby.name)

        user.append(userHobbies)
        response.append(user)


data = serializers.serialize('json', response)
```

Comment: How did you try to seriialize the json ?

Comment: And from what package did you get the "serializers" ?

Comment: django.core.serializers is the package.

Comment: Django's serializers are very basic and only support pure querysets. For anything more complex, use the much more flexible serializers found in Django REST Framework.

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [django github repository](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/serializers/base.py#L75) the `serialize` method expects a queryset.

What you could do is to do a `json.dumps(response)` and return that in the `HttpResponse`.